# Patrial Fraction definite integral with non-real part

Tags: logarithms, partial-fractions

I have a question to find the area bounded by $y = \dfrac{x^2-4x-4}{x^2-4x-5}$ and the x-axis.  First I found the bounds by solving where the numerator would equal zero.  My result is $2\pm2\sqrt2$ so I wrote the integral as follows:

$$\int_{2-2\sqrt2}^{2+2\sqrt2}\dfrac{x^2-4x-4}{(x-5)(x+1)}$$

Then I used partial fractions to split the integral.  The final result I got prior to evaluation at the bounds to find the area is:

$$x + \dfrac{\ln(x-5)}{6}-\dfrac{\ln(x+1)}{6}\bigg|_{2-2\sqrt2}^{2+2\sqrt2}$$

My question is, when I go to plug in the bounds, I get a negative answer inside the first log ($\ln(2+2\sqrt2-5) = \ln(-0.171))$, so that part is not real.  I checked over my integral a couple times and I get the same result, although it's possible I'm missing something somewhere.  If the result above is correct, how do you deal with the non-real portion after evaluating the bounds?

Comment: Doesn't $\int \frac{1}{x}=\ln|x|$? (Note the absolute value signs)

Comment: Oh my gosh, I feel so dumb...yes, I guess I've been working on this for too long and I'm starting to make stupid mistakes...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to start at the partial fractions bit (this isn't *necessarily for* the OP because he already knows how to do it. Rather, it is for other people who may come across a similar problem).
$$\frac{x^2-4x-4}{x^2-4x-5}=1-\frac{1}{x^2-4x-5}$$
I will ignore the $1$ for now. Just remember that the $1$ is still there.
$$\frac{9}{(x-5)(x+1)}$$
$$=\frac{A}{x-5}+\frac{B}{x+1}$$
$$A(x+1)+B(x-5)=1$$
$$Ax+Bx+A-5B=1$$
Now we have a linear system of equations, where $A+B=0$ (this deals with the $x$ term) and $A-5B=1$ (this deals with the constant)
$$\begin{cases} A+B=0 \\ A-5B=1 \\ \end{cases}$$
We can solve by elimination.
$$\begin{array}{align} & A & + & B & = & 0 \\ - & (A & - & 5B) & = & 1 \\ \hline & & & 6B & = & -1 \\ & & & B & = & -\frac{1}{6} \end{array}$$
Plugging back into either equation:
$$A-\frac{1}{6}=0$$
$$A=\frac{1}{6}$$
$$\frac{9}{x^2-4x-5}=\frac{\frac{1}{6}}{x-5}+\frac{-\frac{1}{6}}{x+1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{6(x-5)}-\frac{1}{6(x+1)}$$
Don't forget that $1$! Now we solve for the indefinite integral
$$\int \frac{x^2-4x-4}{x^2-4x-5} \ dx$$
Using our partial fractions:
$$\int 1+\frac{1}{6(x-5)}-\frac{1}{6(x+1)} \ dx$$
$$=\int 1 \ dx + \int \frac{1}{6(x-5)} \ dx - \int \frac{1}{6(x+1)} \ dx$$
The integral of $1$ is $x$.
$$x+\int \frac{1}{6(x-5)} \ dx -\int \frac{1}{6(x+1} \ dx$$
Apply constant rule
$$x+\frac{1}{6} \int \frac{1}{x-5} \ dx -\frac{1}{6}\int \frac{1}{x+1} \ dx$$
Let's work on each integral one by one. Let's start with the first one.
$$\int \frac{1}{x-5} \ dx$$
Let:
$$u=x-5, \ du=dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{u} \ du$$
$$=\ln|u|$$
$$=\ln|x-5|$$
The second integral can be solved in the same way. Let:
$$u=x+1, \ du=dx$$
$$\int \frac{1}{u} \ du$$
$$=\ln|u|$$
$$=\ln|x+1|$$
$$\int \frac{x^2-4x-4}{x^2-4x-5}=x+\frac{1}{6}\ln|x-5| -\frac{1}{6}\ln |x+1| + C$$
$$=x+\frac{\ln|x-5|}{6}-\frac{\ln|x+1|}{6}+C$$
Now we solve for the definite integral. We can ignore the $+C$ because it is only going to get canceled out.
$$\left.x+\frac{\ln|x-5|}{6}-\frac{\ln|x+1|}{6}\right|_{2-\sqrt{2}}^{2+\sqrt{2}}$$
$$=\left(2+\sqrt{2}+\frac{\ln\left|2+\sqrt{2}-5\right|}{6}-\frac{\ln\left|2+\sqrt{2}+1\right|}{6}\right)-\left(2-\sqrt{2}+\frac{\ln\left|2-\sqrt{2}-5\right|}{6}-\frac{\ln\left|2-\sqrt{2}+1\right|}{6}\right)$$
$$=2+\sqrt{2}+\frac{\ln\left|2+\sqrt{2}-5\right|}{6}-\frac{\ln\left|2+\sqrt{2}+1\right|}{6}-2+\sqrt{2}-\frac{\ln\left|2-\sqrt{2}-5\right|}{6}+\frac{\ln\left|2-\sqrt{2}+1\right|}{6}$$
$$=2\sqrt{2}+\frac{\ln\left|\sqrt{2}-3\right|-\ln\left|\sqrt{2}+3\right|}{6}+\frac{\ln\left|3-\sqrt{2}\right|-\ln\left|-\sqrt{2}-3\right|}{6}$$
$$=\frac{12\sqrt{2}+\ln\left|\sqrt{2}-3\right|-\ln\left|\sqrt{2}+3\right|+\ln\left|3-\sqrt{2}\right|-\ln\left|-\sqrt{2}-3\right|}{6}$$
We can simplify the $\left|-\sqrt{2}-3\right|$ in the numerator to $\sqrt{2}+3$. We can also get rid of the absolute value bars in $\left|\sqrt{2}+3\right|$.
$$\frac{12\sqrt{2}+\ln\left|\sqrt{2}-3\right|-\ln\left(\sqrt{2}+3\right)+\ln\left|3-\sqrt{2}\right|-\ln\left(\sqrt{2}+3\right)}{6}$$
$$=\frac{12\sqrt{2}+\ln\left|\sqrt{2}-3\right|-2\ln\left(\sqrt{2}+3\right)+\ln\left|3-\sqrt{2}\right|}{6}$$
$$\color{green}{\therefore \int_{2-\sqrt{2}}^{2+\sqrt{2}} \frac{x^2-4x-4}{x^2-4x+5} \ dx=\frac{12\sqrt{2}+\ln\left|\sqrt{2}-3\right|-2\ln\left(\sqrt{2}+3\right)+\ln\left|3-\sqrt{2}\right|}{6}}$$
If you want a decimal approximation, just plug in that whole entire string of $\ln$s and whatnot into your calculator, or just use an online definite integral calculator. I hope I helped you.

Answer (score 2):

As @JChau mentioned in his comment to my question, my mistake was forgetting to include the absolute value when taking the integral.  Silly mistake!  Thank you.